# How to make a direct link to get the uri segment

Tags: php, model-view-controller, uri, redirect, codeigniter-3

Hello everyone i would ask something about how to direct link with get a uri segment. in my web application, i would make a direct link with get uri segment like this

```
http://localhost/ttaportal/ref_application/manage_access/18
```

i have a controller

```
function insert_access(){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $refAppAccess  = $this->input->post('accessId');
    $refApplicationId  = $this->input->post('appId');
    $refDepartmentId  = $this->input->post('deptId');

    $data = array(
                "refApplicationId" => $refApplicationId,
                "refDepartmentId" => $refDepartmentId
            );
    $action = $this->ref_application_model->insert_access($data);           
    if($action == 1) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Application access has been added successfully');
    }
    else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Failed to add application access');
    }

    redirect(base_url() . 'ref_application/manage_access/'.$id, 'refresh');
}
```

i already try with this but always redirect to

```
http://localhost/ttaportal/ref_application/
```

I really need help. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use base_url for redirect

```
 redirect('/controller/method/id');
```

Or you can also try out(If in same controller)

```
$this->methodName($id);
```

Comment: what code is present in your `ref_application` controller?

Comment: l already try this and my method name $this->manage_acces($id); but redirect to http://localhost/ttaportal/ref_application/ i would to redirect to http://localhost/ttaportal/ref_application/manage_acces/$id